# VBA Macro to delete rows based on the users input

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a macro that will delete all rows below a user specified number. For example the user will put in "19" and the macro will delete rows 20 and below. I really appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Try writing one, and if you can't make any progress, post your code, and people will help.  This is more of a help you over the hump site that a do it all for you site.

Comment: Yes my original description was rather ambiguous. I meant 20-65536.

Comment: + 1 @GrayFox374: I had seen your comment 30 mins ago and out of respect didn't post a code sample but when I saw incorrect code samples were posted, I couldn't help myself. I apologize for the same.

Comment: I know!  It's hard not to contribute, even though it only encourages them! LOL.  Some of us are addicted to problem solving!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- it is expected that questions here relate to specific programming problems. Please post what you have tried and specifically where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. I have used `ActiveSheet`. You can set it to any sheet that you would like to work with.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Long

    Ret = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter a row number", Type:=1)

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    With ActiveSheet
        .Rows(Ret + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter into column=1 and Row=1 the number of the row you want to keep.  The data is in rows=deleterowsbefore every row back to row=2 will be deleted.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

    deleterowsbefore = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    Rows("2:" & deleterowsbefore - 1).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub UserInput()
    Dim num As Integer
    num = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the row number.", Title:="Enter Row Number", Default:="Row number")
    If (num < 1) Then
        GoTo Whoops:
    End If
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do While i <= num
        Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    GoTo Fin:
    Whoops:
        MsgBox ("You have entered an invalid row number")
    Fin:
End Sub
```

Comment: You should never ever need to use `GoTo` in VBA. There are always better ways. And I think that the OP used "Row 20 and below" to mean rows 20-65536 (or whatever, it can vary), not rows 1-19. Admittedly, that's ambiguous.

Comment: I see no problem with using `GoTo` here; it's simple enough.  And I interpreted "20 and below" as "20 and row numbers less than 20 aka 1-19."

Comment: See what one of the best Excel MVP said about GoTo please: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm. I really can't upvote an answer using GoTo sorry

Comment: Hmmm, I reluctantly must agree with @AndrewLeach and JMax - GOTO should never be 'gone to' in 2012.  I used to use it when I was first learning to code on my Commodore 64 back in the day, but never as a professional.  It works, but that is a slippery slope to hackery.

Comment: `GoTo Fin:` looks pointless here. Simply use `Exit Sub`, it's the same thing.

Comment: I agree, no need for any goto's here and while we are all picking on you,  note: the amount of rows in excel exceeds the integer range, use long instead as best practise.  Excel's underlying methods convert integer to long anyway and in actual fact it has been proven that long will execute faster than integer.